# How to create an emacs macro for text templates

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp

I am new to lisp and I am having trouble figuring out how to create a macro in emacs with the following functionality: Say I am tired of writing out the pattern in c++ for a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

}
```

Call this macro "forloop" then I would like to do the following: when I type "M-x forloop" the macro prints out

```
for (int
```

in the buffer and waits for an input. Then I type "i" and hit return after which the macro continues and prints

```
for (int i = 0; i <
```

And again waits for input.  Finally after I type "N" and hit return the macro finishes by printing the rest:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

}
```

After some extensive reading and testing, I was able to write simple lisp functions, create my own macros, save them and call them and so on... but I still can't quite figure out how to make a macro that does something like I have described above.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Macros like this could be really nice for speeding up coding in any language. I would prefer the macro to be dynamic in the way described so that you don't have to remember how many arguments it needs and in which order they go when calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use yasnippet (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) for this, but there are a lot of other solution.

In yasnippet you type a keyword for you snippet (say for) then the yasnippet key shortcut, then you have field to fill, using tab to go from one field to the next.

Every snippet is define in is own file in some easy to learn DSL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything better than `yasnippet` for this problem.
Here's the relevant snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
#name : for (...; ...; ...) { ... }
# --
for (unsigned int ${1:i}=0; $1<${2:N}; ++$1)$0
```

Note that there are two arguments (zero is the exit point),
both have default values, but you can change them by just typing.

### key binding for `yasnippet`

I highly recommend to bind `yas/expand` to <kbd>C-o</kbd>, so it
doesn't conflict with `auto-complete-mode`.
The default binding for this shortcut is near-useless, but it's in
a great position:

```
(global-set-key "\C-o" 'aya-open-line)

(defun aya-open-line ()
  (interactive)
  (cond ((expand-abbrev))

        ((yas/snippets-at-point)
         (yas/next-field-or-maybe-expand-1))

        (((yas/expand)))))
```

This way, the shortcut for expanding and moving to the next field
is the same, which makes you very quick.
Also note that `expand-abbrev` takes precedence: you can fill
an abbrev table for `c++-mode` for the stuff that you use.
Abbrevs don't take an argument, but they all live in one table,
instead of each yasnippet living in its own file, so it's
very easy to edit abbrevs.

### special function to insert curly braces

I wouldn't recommend putting the braces in `yasnippet`,
since sometimes you need them and sometimes you don't.
I use this function instead:

```
(defun ins-c++-curly ()
  "Insert {}."
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "\\()\\|try\\|else\\|const\\|:\\)$")
      (progn
        (insert " {\n\n}")
        (indent-according-to-mode)
        (forward-line -1)
        (indent-according-to-mode))
    (insert "{}") 
    (backward-char))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see similar macros in `sgml-mode.el`, for example `html-href-anchor`, which inserts an HREF anchor (obviously :-).

You will get more specific answers if you tag this as [elisp].

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this and wondering exactly how to do what I requested with yasnippit, here is my yasnippit file:

```
# name: fori ... { ... }
# key: fori
# --
for (int ${1:intname} = 0; ${1:$(yas-substr text "[^: ]*")} < ${2:max}; ${1:$(yas-substr text "[^: ]*")}++) {
$0
}
```

Note that yasnippit already has a function for "for" in c++ mode, but I did not like the way it behaved.

Conclusion, yasnippit is awesome and super easy!  Thanks for the suggestion!